# How to append data from ajax remote request to <div> without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url + "/data",
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token)
    },
    success: function(data){
        if (data[0].err) {
            $("#data").append(data[0].err);
        }
        else {
            localStorage.setItem("localdata", data[0].status);
            $("#data").append(data[0].status);
        }
    }
});
```

I am designing a single page Hybrid HTML5 App, In the above code, everything is working fine, but the data is displayed only when the page is refreshed. How do i display the data without page refresh.

The above is just a example code. I have a separate div for login and dashboard, when logged in, it fetches remote data and redirects to dashboard div(single page app), but the data is not displayed instead it is blank. But on refreshing the page, it gets displayed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that it has to do with the authorization and the server-side script. Try removing the auth restriction from the server-side script to test it. Also, you could try running a second AJAX call in the `success` method of the first call.

Comment: I just tried without the authentication, data is displayed only after a page refresh. I am using .append to print data to a div.